# For loop java not executing properly?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

```
//Declared here the atributes int id and int [9][5] array.

public String getPos(int id){
String res = "";
for(int i = 0; i <9 ;i++ ){
    for(int j = 0; j<5 ;j++){
        if(this.arr[i][j] == id)
              res = res + i + "," + j;  
    }
}
return res;
}
```

When I run getPos(1); the result is 8,2 but i want it to print 9,3. How i do that?

Comment: Maybe add 1 to `i` and `j`?

Comment: Obviously _not_ by using `res + (i + 1) + "," + (j + 1);`. Btw: I guess you want `return res + ...` instead of `res = res + ...`. Or do you expect (and what) to get multiples matches?

Comment: Do you remember that Java indices are zero-based?

Comment: `i` will never equal `9` in that loop.  And how can we possibly know what's in `arr`?  It's really not clear what the problem is here.

Comment: "When I run getPos(1); the result is 8,2 but i want it to print 9,3. How i do that?" You'll have to give a bit more information than that.. We only see the part of the code provided by you. We don't know what's inside the `arr`-array. We now know that it prints something wrong, and what you want it to print instead, but we don't know **why** it prints something wrong according to you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java indexes allways start with 0. so 0,0 would be the very first element.

Just add 1 to both found indexes befor returning.

Also: Can an "id" be found at multiple positions, or is it unique?

If it is unique and you allways want the result to be returned as "x,y" you should immediatly return as soon as you found the id:

```
public String getPos(int id){
for(int i = 0; i <9 ;i++ ){
    for(int j = 0; j<5 ;j++){
        if(this.arr[i][j] == id)
              return (i+1) + "," + (j+1);  
    }
}
```

If an id can be found multiple times, you have to think about how to mark those multiple results, because currently you program could possibly return something like "1,56,2" (if supplied id is found at both 1,5 and 6,2)

Something like:

```
public String getPos(int id){
String res = "";
for(int i = 0; i <9 ;i++ ){
    for(int j = 0; j<5 ;j++){
        if(this.arr[i][j] == id)
              res = res +"["+ (i+1) + "," + (j+1)+"]";  
    }
}
return res;
```

^- would return "[1,5][6,2]", wrapping found results in braces and making them more readable.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked with (i+1) + (j+1) and now prints 9,3!